# NUnit/C#: How to enable/disable some automation tests (Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Id like to have one file or class, in which i can control, which tests should be executed.

I know there is TestNG for Java, which can be used for that.

But i cant find anything for C# in google or here in stackoverflow related to this problem

My current test framework has 17 automation tests (17 classes) and much more will be added this year.

Therefor id like to have one file/class/method, in which i can set, which tests should be executed/not executed, as i don't want every test to be triggered, when i'm actively working on 2-3 automation tests.

My first idea:

- In NUnit we can set a [Ignore("reason")] parameter above the class or method, which skips this test.
  Is it possible to control these parameter outside of the class?

Id be happy and thankful for any other suggestions!

Comment: you can provide a `where`-clause to nunit-console in order to filter the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Nunit is the way to go for a single class with however many @Test methods you create.
You can use The @Ignore annotation you suggested to filter out tests that are not ready, or just dont want to execute.

And You can also use [Event Listeners](https://docs.nunit.org/2.5/eventListeners.html). Very useful tool that will help you control the actions of before, after, fail, pass etc... processed of all your tests. you can specify a condition on the unwanted tests and in the "TestStarted" event listener you Assert an ignore, this will effect all your tests marked by the specific condition.

Comment: Thanks! So is my approach of my test framework wrong? Our app has 4 different features(links). For each feature i created a own class. For example: Features name is "UnlockInstruction", so i created a UnlockInstructionTest.cs in which i have methods that do test all the parts of that feature. Or do i understand your first paragraph wrong? Maybe you could show me an example with the @Test methods?

Comment: I would approach this differently, yes. Every feature or "End-to-End" process or simply Test is made of several actions. those action can be stored as methods in a designated class called "Business Actions" for example, every action method consist of several selenium actions. in your main class, where you run your tests, each method is a different test with @test annotation, and it can hold several of those pre-made business actions. this will allow you to reuse the business actions in each of your tests, no need to create different class for every test.

Comment: I see, a bit hard to understand. If you allow me to explain my framework. Ive got a SeleniumUtils class, which is my so called 'library'. It contains methods with all important actions which im using during the selenium test. Then i have for each feature, 2 additional classes. One is FeaturesNameTest.cs and the other FeaturesNamePage.cs. The FeaturesNameTest contains testdata and initialize the test. It creates there the chrome driver. The FeatureNamePage contains all the steps which are being done on the website. It is being called by the FeatureNameTest and returns true if every step is done

Comment: I see, does every feature you test has unique url and/or not connected with each other? if not, and every feature is just another aspect of the same system/site than I see no reason to instantiate a different driver for every test. you should keep every page of every feature in a different class, that's great. however IMO you should get rid of your unique class for every test and put them all under the same class with a single driver instantiated and use a single method called @afterMethod to go back to the origin point from which every test can be executed (using UI actions).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! The website contains on the left side a menu with 5 different buttons, which each of the buttons represent a feature. So yeah each feature is in the same system/website. The problem is, the app is not done yet. A lot new feature will be added to it this year. If i would have one class with all Test Methods inside, then the class would get longer and longer which i want to prevent. I know what you want to tell me. But are there any "negative" side effects when i create for each test a own webdriver? After each test (No matter if pass or fail) it kills the chromedriver

Comment: Oh, and each of these features is being tested with 2 different users using the [TestFixture(" - - - ")] NUnit parameter